# Reset StripeCardComponent after adding Stripe card

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, stripe-payments, ionic4

I use StripeCardComponent with [ngx-stripe](https://github.com/nomadreservations/ngx-stripe). Do you know how to reset the form after adding the Stripe card?

```
<ngx-stripe-card [options]="cardOptions" [elementsOptions]="elementsOptions" (change)="cardUpdated($event)" (error)="error = $event"></ngx-stripe-card>
<div class="error">
  {{error?.message}}
</div>
<button (click)="getCardToken()" [disabled]="!complete">Get Card Token</button>
```

I have tried like below. But it is not working.

```
addcard(){
 (document.querySelector('.ElementsApp') as HTMLFormElement).reset();
}
```

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'reset' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of null

Run time Html

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. This works nicely.

```
addCard(){
    this.element.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More sophisticated way:

Send the html element of ngx-stripe to your function and reset it

HTML:

```
<ngx-stripe-card [options]="cardOptions" [elementsOptions]="elementsOptions" (change)="cardUpdated($event)"
#myStripeElement
 ></ngx-stripe-card>

<button (click)="clearForm(myStripeElement)">Clear form</button>
```

Component:

```
clearForm(myStripeElement:any) {
    myStripeElement.element.clear()
}
```